# Outsource identifiers of e4xmi to java class

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

Does anyone know if it is possible to outsource the identifiers of an `e4xmi` file to a java class. I know that it is possible to outsource the strings of labels and descriptions to a properties file, but it would also be very convenient to outsource the identifiers of this elements. For one thing you could then easily reference from your other java classes to this strings and on the other hand if you change one of the identifiers they will remain consistent among all your editors ...
At the moment it is very annoying if you have several editors which refer to this identifier and you have to change the identifier than you have to change it on several places which is always very error-prone ... 
[image]

Thanks for any help or pointers in advance.

Comment: No there is currently no way to do this.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok what a pity, that would be a nice feature for the future ;) But thanks anyway for the quick respond.